# how to install unixodbc on linux

Tags: linux, unixodbc

I am trying to install unixodbc on linux (clean install of ubuntu 20), but the directions [here](https://odbc.postgresql.org/) are not working for me. When I get the step to `./configure` , I get an error saying "configure: error: odbc_config not found (required for unixODBC build)".

Given that this is a popular package and the instructions on the main website don't work, I'm wondering if someone in that community could help me install it?

I tried installing it directly from a .deb file which appeared to work with 0 exit status, but I am still getting an error when I try to run `odbc_config`, which is how they say to verify the installation. And `which unixodbc` returns nothing.

Any help installing this package on linux would be greatly appreciated!

Note: On mac, `brew install unixodbc` works just fine. But I am running into problems when using the compiled binaries from that installation on a linux machine -- it is giving me a mysterious `file not found` error when I try to reference it, even though it is there, so I believe I need to compile it on linux in order to get it to work.

EDIT: I tried installing from source, but then I got a different error: libpq library version = 9.2 is required. Is there any way to install this package on ubuntu without having to set all kinds of special flags?

EDIT2: I was able to get the installation process to complete after installing libpq-dev.

Comment: apt install unixodbc ?

Comment: I built `unixodbc` from source and managed to get it to work. `odbc_config` wasn't installed with the `unixodbc` for me and I also found some posts online confirming this "issue".

Comment: @oakad when I tried that it said there was no package found called unixodbc. should have mentioned that.

Comment: It merely means that it is not available in the "main" repo, but can be available elsewhere: https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/20.04/ubuntu-universe-amd64/unixodbc_2.3.6-0.1build1_amd64.deb.html

Comment: Also: https://askubuntu.com/questions/148638/how-do-i-enable-the-universe-repository